# In what order should I play The Witcher games?

Tags: the-witcher-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much of The Witcher 2 will I have trouble with, not having played the first game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22391/how-much-of-the-witcher-2-will-i-have-trouble-with-not-having-played-the-first-g)

Does *The Witcher 2* continue the story of *The Witcher 1*? If so, is it recommended to play The Witcher 1 before 2?