# How can I safely start playing The Witcher 2 without having played it's predecessor all the way through?

Tags: the-witcher-2, the-witcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much of The Witcher 2 will I have trouble with, not having played the first game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22391/how-much-of-the-witcher-2-will-i-have-trouble-with-not-having-played-the-first-g)

I played The Witcher for tens of hours. If I remember correctly I stopped playing just as I was doing a bossfight outside the wizard's tower in the marshlands. Now I've lost the game save, and I want to know what happens from that point in the game so I can safely play The Witcher 2.

I've searched for a video playthrough or a text walkthrough with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playthrough video will take you a lot of time since witcher is pretty long game and there is much killing,questing,walking... which is not relevant to the story.

You can check wiki for details that you are interested in,like characters or so but the short story should be enough since it considers all important things from witcher 1 that are in witcher 2.

[http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_(short_story)](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_%28short_story%29)

Note that lot of characters just dissapear and some apper from W1 to W2