# Is Witcher 2 very different to Witcher 1?

Tags: the-witcher-2, the-witcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much of The Witcher 2 will I have trouble with, not having played the first game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22391/how-much-of-the-witcher-2-will-i-have-trouble-with-not-having-played-the-first)

I've tried to play the first Witcher game a few times now and just haven't been able to get into it, just keep getting distracted by other things and forgetting the story so far and end up starting again. I've heard great things about the Witcher 2 but was wondering if it's sufficiently different for me to be able to enjoy it. 
For context I am a big fan of CRPG games including (in a rough descending order): Baldur's Gate, Planescape: Torment, KOTOR, Oblivion+Skyrim, Mount and Blade, Fable...

Comment: Different how?  Combat style?  Sandbox aspects?  Story?

Comment: Voting to reopen because, well, it's not a duplicate. The other question is about plot and this isn't.

Comment: Not voting to re-open because the other question isn't exclusively about plot and the answer there already covers the question asked here.

Comment: @kotekzot If this isn't a dupe then your answer skews it towards bad subjective by inviting extended discussion and arguments :)

Comment: I voted to close as not constructive.  I don't think its a duplicate, but I also believe we've decided to avoid "Compare Game X to Game Y" questions, even when both games are in the same series.

Comment: You might want to read my [blog post on the subject](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/04/the-witcher-2-enhanced-edition/) - I similarly did not finish the first before starting the second.  In this game, the combat is tricky and weird, and involves a lot of running away.

Answer (score -7):

Well, it is different by being worse - the combat is a lot more boring as Geralt adopts a fighting style befitting a frontline soldier and not a witcher, who are famed for their bombastic acrobatics. The most interesting move you'll see Geralt perform in the sequel is a roll to the side. Alchemy is also much less useful due to most potions having their active time reduced by an order of magnitude and you having to spend 30 seconds navigating a menu and watching an animation of Geralt kneeling and taking a deep breath, and of course you can no longer take potions during a battle. You are also encouraged to stop in your tracks every 10 seconds and fondle your medallion to locate objects you can interact with, replacing the *massively inconvenient* system of displaying labels above things you can interact with.

Comment: @kotekzot Opinions don't make for very good answers. While I understand what you were trying to do, it should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Fluttershy I have to disagree with you. "Witcher 2 is worse" is an opinion, "Witcher 2 is worse because of a, b and c" is fact with an opinion on top.

Comment: And if some else were to actually *like* the changes that you list as "fact"? Surely you see the issue here.

Comment: @Fluttershy well then they can form their own opinions, I'm not writing gospel, that still doesn't change the facts. Should I remove "worse" from the answer and add a comment saying "P.S. it's horrible"?